# Eliminate Recursive CTE

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions, common-table-expression, recursive-query

Everyone,

I hope that someone out there can help me at getting same result and eliminate this recursive CTE.  It sounds simple in principle but I have been working on this for at least a couple of days and can't come up with anything.  One final thing, I am aware of the OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0) option.  This is not a feasible option for us.  We are in a production environment and don't want the database to come to a crawl.  If possible we would like to get away from the recursive CTE.

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @StartDate), 0) AS StartOfMonth, 
               DATEADD(s, 0, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @StartDate) + 1, 0)) AS EndOfMonth
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, StartOfMonth) AS StartOfMonth, 
               DATEADD(s, 0, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, DATEADD(month, 1, StartOfMonth)) + 1, 0)) AS EndOfMonth  
        FROM   cte
        WHERE  DATEADD(month, 1, StartOfMonth) <= @EndDate
)
```

The above code in resides in a Table-valued Function in SQL Server called fn_SplitPeriodIntoMonths.

One can call the function

```
SELECT * FROM fn_SplitPeriodIntoMonths('2018-01-01','2018-09-01')
```

And then the result is this

```
StartOfMonth                   EndOfMonth
2018-01-01 00:00:00.000        2018-02-01 00:00:00.000
2018-02-01 00:00:00.000        2018-03-01 00:00:00.000
2018-03-01 00:00:00.000        2018-04-01 00:00:00.000
2018-04-01 00:00:00.000        2018-05-01 00:00:00.000
2018-05-01 00:00:00.000        2018-06-01 00:00:00.000
2018-06-01 00:00:00.000        2018-07-01 00:00:00.000
2018-07-01 00:00:00.000        2018-08-01 00:00:00.000
2018-08-01 00:00:00.000        2018-09-01 00:00:00.000
2018-09-01 00:00:00.000        2018-10-01 00:00:00.000
```

As you can see the result is a breakdown of the periods by months.  Rather cool.  One can then use this in a any number of ways.  But if one were to call this with a select that has "too" many rows, we hit the MAXRECUSION LIMIT.

Any help would very much be appreciated.

All the best,

George

Comment: There's only so many months in the history and future of the world and we already know what they are. Why not just store these two columns in a table instead of dynamically creating them every time you need it? Once and done. Then just use the table.

Comment: Make a calendar table, and an Integers function.

Comment: A calendar table is a good approach but you could also use a tally table to eliminate this because it is essentially just counting.

Comment: have you measured a problem with the recursive CTE approach?  Why would you slow to a crawl?  If you make a populated months table, you can put indexes on it etc - which may benefit your queries.  Other than that, another method is CROSS JOINING sub-queries of months, decades, years, centuries, and building the same table 'on-the fly'  (I did see someone claim it beats the CTE method for performance)

Comment: you don't need to have OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0) how about OPTION(MAXRECURSION 2500)  - that's over 200 years of months maximum, but it wouldn't risk generating for ages if someone sent a year such as 9999 in (there is a maximum year, your CTE would never run forever)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[fn_SplitPeriodIntoMonths]    Script Date: 24/07/2018 17:29:05 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Andy Deighton
-- Create date: 24/07/2018
-- Description: Return a date table
-- =============================================
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_SplitPeriodIntoMonths]
(   
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @START DATE,
    @END DATE
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(

    SELECT AM.StartOfMonth, EOMONTH(AM.StartOfMonth) EndOfMonth FROM
    (
    SELECT datefromparts(100 * (c.century - 1) + 10 * (d.decade -1) + y.[year],M.[month],1) StartOfMonth                   
                                  FROM 
                                  (SELECT 20 century UNION SELECT 21) C
                                    CROSS JOIN 
                                    (SELECT decade FROM 
                                                (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6),(7),(8),(9), (10)) 
                                                    X(decade)) D
                                    CROSS JOIN 
                                    (SELECT [year] FROM 
                                                (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5),(6),(7),(8), (9)) 
                                                    X([year])) Y
                                    CROSS JOIN 
                                    (SELECT [month] FROM 
                                                (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5),(6),(7),(8), (9), (10), (11),(12)) 
                                                    X([month])) M
    ) AM WHERE AM.StartOfMonth BETWEEN @START AND @END




)
```

sample call

```
    select * from dbo.fn_SplitPeriodIntoMonths('19660101','20450101') order by startofmonth
```

Comment: Thanks for all the comments guys.  Cato, that is one awesome query you came up with.